# Solr how exclude number or regex in facet results

Tags: solr, facet

I have an issue to exclude numbers from a facet result.

My call is

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core/select?q=content:covid&facet=true&facet.field=content&facet.limit=10&facet.minCount=1&facet.excludeTerms=i,me,my,myself,we,our
```

I got

```
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "content":[
        "covid",27,
        "19",5,
        "from", 18,
        "2020", 3,
        ...
]},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}}
```

But I don't want to get the numbers 19 & 2020 (in fact I don't want any number in my result). But I still need to get 10 results (so I can't set to an upper random limit and filter my result in a 2nd time -> wrong).

I tried to put some regex into facet.contains, facet.queries, facet.excludeTerms without any result.

Help with https://1opensourcelover.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/solr-regex-tutorial/

As anybody an idea or a solution please ?

Comment: The most effective way is to create a second field that contains valid faceting terms from your input content - instead of trying to use the same field as you use for your main search. That way you can do any filtering you'd like to with analysis filters or with an update request processor in your field definition. You can use a copy field instruction to get the same content as you have for your `content` field into a `content_facet` field.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh. So a 2nd field with only alphabetical content in my case (no number at all). It may works for sure, but it seems quite greedy no ? The texts I have in these contents are long.